# How to make html look disabled?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I read in some forums that to make an html table look disabled is to add a layer of div. My problem is I don't know how to do it.

I have 3 questions:

1. How will I set the div height that it will automatically adjust to the table height whenever the table increases its height when a new row is added.
2. How will I make the div cover the table. I don't know how to layer html elements.
3. How am I going to code the javascript that will make my table look disabled when I click 'Disable' button and enable it again when I click 'Enable' button.

**tabledisabletest.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<style type="text/css">
 table#tblTest {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #666666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 table#tblTest tr.highlight td {
  background-color: #8888ff;
 }

 table#tblTest tr.normal {
  background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 table#tblTest th {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #dedede;
 }

 table#tblTest td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 #disabler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity:0.6;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="disabler"></div>

 <table id="tblTest">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Tom</td>    
    <td>UK </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Henrik</td> 
    <td>Denmark</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Lionel</td> 
    <td>Italy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Ricardo</td>    
    <td>Brazil</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cristiano</td>  
    <td>Portugal</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="button" onclick="disable = true;" value="Disable" />
 <input type="button" onclick="disable = false;" value="Enable" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have the div `disabler` to do the disabling but I can't make it cover the table.

Please help me with this. I'm  so new to this thing.

Comment: Suggestion: Use jQuery BlockUI. Demos: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Comment: I think I need to learn the native javascript first before jumping into some advanced technology. Also I need to learn javascript because I need to prepare for an exam.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by making it *look disabled*? Can the user still select text from it? Does it need to have those borders and shadow effects you see on disabled controls?

Comment: Is it possible to disable text selecting? I want to make it look like a disabled control.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the `disabler` element to overlay your table, add a negative bottom-margin to it. Also, set `opacity` to a value lower than 1, to not completely cover (hide) the table behind it.

```
 #disabler {
     opacity: 0.5;
     margin-bottom: -200px;
 }
```

Since you've mentioned that you're doing this for educative purposes, I won't give the full solution. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAb8b/)** to get started.

If you want to make a text look "unselectable", use the following CSS:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: Thanks but how am I gonna make it to automatically adjust when a new row is inserted in the table.

Comment: @ChickenBoy Use JavaScript. The `height` of an element can be changed using `element.style.height = height + "px";` (where `height` is a number)`. To get the size of an element, use `element.offsetHeight`. **See http://jsfiddle.net/RAb8b/1/** for additional JavaScript code. **Again: I am not showing the full solution, *just* useful hints**, so that you learn something. The best way to learn is by getting experience and committing errors.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to place the `div` `disabler` on top of the table.

You can do so by absolutely positioning the `div`. I added a new div, tableContainer enveloping the disabler div and the table, and absolutely positioning the div.

```
<div id="tableContainer">   <!-- New Div-->
   <div id="disabler"></div>
   <table>....<table>
</div>
```

Add `position: absolute;` to the `#disabler`

And **most importantly** write the javascript to display and hide the div:

```
function disableTable()
{
  document.getElementById("disabler").style.display = "block";
}

function enableTable()
{
  document.getElementById("disabler").style.display = "none";
}
```

Live Example: http://jsbin.com/icuwug